# Use JavaScript Proxy to prepend value to argument

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to work with my REST API.  The API serves multiple apps with routes of the form `/api/<app>/...`.

In my "mp" app client, I'm constantly repeating the string `Axios.[rest-method]('/api/mp/[...]', ...)`.  I thought a clever way to avoid this would be to wrap Axios in a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).  With this proxied object, I could make my calls like `Axios.mp.get(...)` and it would automatically prepend `/api/mp` to the first argument of `get()`.

Obviously, I could create my own wrapper object with wrapped REST methods that did this, but where's the fun in that?

Here's what I have so far:

```js
import AxiosLib from 'axios';

const routes = {
        mp: '/api/mp',
        // ...
    },
    restMethods = new Set([
        'get',
        'post',
        'put',
        'delete',
        'head',
        'patch'
    ]);

const Axios = new Proxy(AxiosLib, {
    get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
        let routePrefix = routes[prop];

        if (routePrefix) {
            // return `receiver` with magic to store `routePrefix`
        } else if (restMethods.has(prop)) {
            let method = Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
            routePrefix = /* get magically stored `routePrefix` if it exists */ || '';
            return function(url, ...args) {
                return method.apply(this, routePrefix + url, ...args);
            }
        } else {
            return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
        }
    }
});

export default Axios;
```

What do I put in the two commented sections?

I could create a new, second-layer Proxy for each defined route that handled this, but for cleanliness's/simplicity's sake, I'd like to use only a single proxy.

Comment: What is the specific problem or question?

Comment: What do I put in the two commented sections?

Comment: I would recommend to try to implement a standard wrapper object first, only then transition to proxies (for fun).